# Using parenthesis and both operators "AND" "OR" in $filter

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I'm trying to query a Sharepoint Online website using REST API with this criteria:

> ProjectStatus = 'In Progress' AND (ProjectName = 'ABC' OR ProjectName = 'XYZ')

So I'm calling the below url:

> /sites/projects/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Projects')/items?$select=Id&$filter=ProjectStatus eq 'In Progress' and (ProjectName eq 'ABC' or ProjectName eq 'XYZ')

But I receive the below message:

> The expression "ProjectStatus eq 'In Progress' and (ProjectName eq 'ABC' or ProjectName eq 'XYZ')" is not valid

If I only use `$filter=ProjectStatus eq 'In Progress'`, it works. It also works if I only use `$filter=(ProjectName eq 'ABC' or ProjectName eq 'XYZ')`. But both together returns a `is not valid`.

We cannot mix `and` and `or` with some parenthesis?

Thanks

Comment: DO you really have ` `"` at the end of the url that is 'not working', and no `"` at the end of the other url's you tested?

Comment: No, it's a bad copy/paste here :-)

Comment: Just did a test on my end, this works for me. You could try to add parentheses to wrp the filter. Check if it works, like this: $filter=(ProjectStatus eq 'In Progress' and (ProjectName eq 'ABC' or ProjectName eq 'XYZ'))

Comment: @MichaelHan_MSFT > I tried pretty much all the combinaisons I could think about, with always the same error… But at least if you say it works for you, I guess it's supposed to work for me… I'll keep trying.